# Fitting a broken stick regression with confidence intervals

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, data-visualization, ggplot2

I have been trying to fit a scatter plot of a broken stick regression with confidence intervals. What I would like is to have two different regression lines and confidence intervals between the inflection point. I've already determined the inflection point using the SiZer package. I have tried to plot this two ways, by trying to graph 2 scatter plots (of the data groups based on the inflection point) with regressions and CIs on one graph, and also by indicating the inflection point (Tb>33.688) in the code, but have just received errors. I would like a graph similar to this, but with 2 different regression lines and CIs around the significant inflection point at 33.688

```
   p<-ggplot (thermalb, aes(x=thermalb$Ta, y=thermalb$Tb))+ 
   geom_point (color= "#69b3a2")+
   xlab("Air temperature (°C)")+ 
   ylab("Body temperature(°C)")+
   geom_smooth(method=lm , color="red", se=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to categorize your observations according to the changepoint, and pass it as group in ggplot, for example:

```
library(SiZer)
library(ggplot2)
data(Arkansas)
dat = Arkansas
model <- piecewise.linear(dat$year,dat$sqrt.mayflies, CI=FALSE)
#group according to the changepoint
dat$grp = factor(ifelse(Arkansas$year > model$change.point,1,0))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=year,y=sqrt.mayflies,group=grp)) + 
geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~x,col="red")
```

[image]